# SQLite read all data operation

Tags: android, sqlite

Please check what problem with this .I am trying to retrive all records in my table (contains 11 records with 3 columns `"name","address","city"`) but my code showing only one i.e last inserted record on my screen. but i need to display all records.

```
public void readData(View v)
    {
        DatabaseClass mydb = new DatabaseClass(this);
        SQLiteDatabase readdata = mydb.getReadableDatabase();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.readtext);
        Cursor c = readdata.rawQuery("select * from mylistdata", null);
        int[] elementId = {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3}; 
        if(c !=null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            while(c.isAfterLast() == false)
            {
                listData = new ArrayList<GenericListItem>();
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.NAME));
                String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.ADDRESS));
                String city = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.CITY));
                listData.add(new GenericListItem(new String[]{name,address,city}));
                listAdapter = new GenericListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_layout, listData, elementId);
                result.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                c.moveToNext();
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize `listData` ArrayList  outside from `While` loop as:

```
    c.moveToFirst();
    listData = new ArrayList<GenericListItem>();
    while(c.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
       // add value here to listData
      c.moveToNext();
    }
   // set  listData datasource to GenericListAdapter here

   listAdapter = new GenericListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
              R.layout.list_layout, listData, elementId);

   result.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that you are re-creating your list each time through the loop.  Try this:

```
listData = new ArrayList<GenericListItem>();  //moved out of loop

 while(c.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.NAME));
            String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.ADDRESS));
            String city = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseClass.CITY));
            listData.add(new GenericListItem(new String[]{name,address,city}));
            listAdapter = new GenericListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_layout, listData, elementId);
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        result.setAdapter(listAdapter);  // moved out of loop
```